# How to count value occurrences in json response using python?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a json response that looks like below and I would like to count how many times `corrId` has been mentioned.

```
{
  "result":
    {
      "corrList":[
        {
          "corrId":123456,
          "title":"sample1",
        },
        {
          "corrId":45678,
          "title":"sample2",
        },
        {
          "corrId":987654,
          "title":"sample3",
        }
      ],
      "find":true
    }
}
```

For the above, I would expect result to be `3`

I have tried something like above, but it throws an error:

```
r = requests.get(url = HOSTNAME + endpoint, headers = headers, verify=False)
data = json.loads(r.text)
corrList = len(data['corrList'][0]['corrId'])
print (corrList)
```

My error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Would someone be able to help? thanks in advance!

Comment: use `len(data['result']['corrList'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually count the number of `dict`s that have that key:

```py
data = {
  "result":
    {
      "corrList":[
        {
          "corrId":123456,
          "title":"sample1",
        },
        {
          "corrId":45678,
          "title":"sample2",
        },
        {
          "corrId":987654,
          "title":"sample3",
        }
      ],
      "find":True
    }
}

corrList = [item for item in data['result']['corrList'] if 'corrId' in item]
print(len(corrList))
```

Output 3